# how to make text with inline image within the container using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been looking for this solution even tried my self but no luck.

I want to make the image from half widh to right edge of the browser

```
<section class="map-cont">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h2 class="main-heading">heading</h2>
                        <p>text</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img src="img/map.jpg" alt="" class="map" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

I want to acheive this, please see the below image.

[image]

Comment: what css do you have right now besides the bootstrap?

Comment: I didn't write much for it thought bootstrap will have something for such requirement.

Comment: Provide jsfiddle with css+html.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write any additional CSS. Just add the Bootstrap class "img-responsive" to your image.

```
<img src="img/map.jpg" alt="" class="map img-resonsive" />
```

From the [Bootstrap 3 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive):

> Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition of the .img-responsive class. This applies max-width: 100%;, height: auto; and display: block; to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.
>
> To center images which use the .img-responsive class, use
>   .center-block instead of .text-center. See the helper classes section
>   for more details about .center-block usage.

**EDIT**: To give the class a margin from the right side of the col-md-6, just over-ride the CSS like this:

```
.img-responsive {
   max-width: 50% !important;
}
```

Note that this changes ALL images with this class so you may need to target it more specifically if you don't want this to be the case.

Comment: Please provide more context for links to external resources. Right now, this isn't a very good answer [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @M.Cotter Its not related to the question but thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what you have in your CSS or an example, my suggestions would be to either re-size your image to fit within the container (if the container is not elastic), or add a `width: 100%` to the image styling to keep the image contained within the container.

Comment: I actually want to make the image from half widh to right edge of the browser

Answer (score 0):

Without using exact bootstrap, you can just create your own css to do what you need to do. I don't know what size your image is but I just made it 300px and then set it to 100% in the container.

https://jsfiddle.net/3s2mv5by/

```
<section class="map-cont">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2 class="main-heading">heading</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <div class="imageholder">
        <img src="img/map.jpg" alt="" width="300px" height="300px" class="map" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

.col-md-6 {
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
}

p, .imageholder {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  float:left;
}
img {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks @keith for your time but it doesn't full fil my requirement. I can actually able to inline the image with text using the above code.